# How to extract the names of unique columns of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Let's suppose I have a table in PorstreSQL defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id serial not null primary key,
  var1 text null,
  var2 text null unique,
  var3 text null,
  var4 text null unique
);
```

Is there a query to `information_schema` that provides the names of unique columns only? The desirable response should be:

```
var2
var4
```

The query should ignore unique keys for multiple columns together.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore unique keys for multiple columns together"?

Comment: I mean the constraint for the unique combination of several fields.

Comment: I have amended the answer for that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `information_schema.table_constraints` and `information_schema.constraint_column_usage`:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS c
   JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS cc
      USING (table_schema, table_name, constraint_name)
WHERE c.constraint_type = 'UNIQUE';
```

If you want to skip constraints with more than one column, use grouping:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, min(column_name)
FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS c
   JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS cc
      USING (table_schema, table_name, constraint_name)
WHERE c.constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'
GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```